# Request method 'DELETE' not supported - reactjs + spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, methods, spring-restcontroller, path-variables

using ReactJs and Springboot app... passing value through JSON 
getting error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'DELETE' not supported]
```

tried these two options.

1.

```
@DeleteMapping("/{companyId}")
         public Long deleteCompany(@PathVariable Long companyId)
```

2.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{Company}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public @ResponseBody void deleteCompany(
            @PathVariable("companyId") Long companyId){
```

from React:

````
export function RemoveCompany(deleteCompany) {
alert(deleteCompany.companyId);
    return request({
        url: API_BASE_URL + "/company", 
        method: 'delete',
        body: JSON.stringify(deleteCompany)
    });
}

in springboot app
```@DeleteMapping(value="company/{companyId}")
    public @ResponseBody void deleteCompany(
            @PathVariable("companyId") Long companyId){
        System.out.printf("Testing: You tried to delete \n");
    }
````

===================
This below reactjs code error.message returns "No Message Available".
and in spring boot app no log messages on this event...

```
RemoveCompany(deleteCompany)
        .then(response => {
            notification.success({
                message: 'company soft',
                description: "Thank you! Company Created Successfully!",
            });          
            this.props.history.push("/company");
        }).catch(error => {
            notification.error({
                message: 'company soft',
                description: error.message || 'Sorry! Something went wrong. Please try again!'
            });
        });
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I am at this error and very curious

Answer (score 1):

You aren't sending companyId in path as expected, but in body,

You can send it in path in React code:

```
 url: API_BASE_URL + "/company/" + deleteCompany.companyId,
```

Or remove companyId from spring boot `@PathVariable` and change to get it from Object holding `String companyId`